# Get offline message of another resource XMPP

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, xmppframework

My app supports multiple clients for the user.
To get messages on all device of the user I implemented [XEP-0280: Message Carbons](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html).
I am getting messages on all resources(clients) while all resources are online but I am not getting an offline message on the resource which is not online.

Let me explain with the example.
UserA logins with the two device iOS and Android. For now, userA is online from both device in this situation userA will get messages on both devices. Now UserA goes offline from iOS device and keep online on Android device in this situation when anyone sends message then Android device getting messages and iOS does not. Whenever userA goes online with the iOS client not getting offline messages which are sent while Android was online.

Please give me solutions if anyone knows.
Thank you so much in advance and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you check the XEPs? I’m not familiar with this case, but [XEP-0013](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0013.html) seems to be relevant.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I am struggling with the same issue.

Comment: I've tried to fetch history via XEP-0313 but I was not able to fetch completely and properly messages if you find any solutions then please add answer. @AftabBaig